# Adding edges create duplicate nodes instead of using the already added nodes

Tags: python, networkx

I added the nodes by passing a dictionary of objects to `add_nodes_from` function.

Then I specified the edges by passing a list to `add_edges_from` function.

When, edges are added they create duplicate nodes instead of using the ones already added before.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from Employee import Employee

G = nx.DiGraph()

employees = {
    "John": Employee("John"),
    "Mathews": Employee("Mathews"),
    "Joseph": Employee("Joseph"),
    "Lana": Employee("Lana"),
    "Debrah": Employee("Debrah"),
    "Greg": Employee("Greg"),
    "Bob": Employee("Bob"),
    "Mary": Employee("Mary"),

}

connections = [
    (employees.get("John"), employees.get("Debrah")),
    (employees.get("John"), employees.get("Mary")),
    (employees.get("Mary"), employees.get("Greg")),
    (employees.get("Mary"), employees.get("Lana")),
    (employees.get("Mary"), employees.get("Debrah")),
    (employees.get("Mathews"), employees.get("Joseph")),
    (employees.get("Mathews"), employees.get("Debrah")),
    (employees.get("Mathews"), employees.get("Mary")),
    (employees.get("Lana"), employees.get("Debrah")),
    (employees.get("Greg"), employees.get("Bob")),

]

G.add_nodes_from(employees)

G.add_edges_from(connections)

print(G.nodes)
```

**Output**

> ['John', 'Mathews', 'Joseph', 'Lana', 'Debrah', 'Greg', 'Bob', 'Mary',
>   John, Debrah, Mary, Greg, Lana, Mathews, Joseph, Bob]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
G.add_nodes_from(employees)
```

This is adding nodes using the keys of the dict (strings)

```
G.add_edges_from(connections)
```

This is adding edges using the values of the dict (employees)

Comment: Thank you. That was a silly mistake on my part. Using employees.values() gets me a list of values from the dictionary.